# Failed to create Environment bean in SpringRunner

Tags: java, springrunner

I need to read properties for unit testing in one of the test class using Environment bean but spring is failed to create environment bean.

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "/application-test.properties")
public class CardTest {

  @Autowired
  Environment environment;

  @Test
  public void givenPropertyFetchesAndValidatesTheValue() {
    String output = environment.getProperty("test");
    assertThat(output).isEqualTo("502123");
  }
}
```

**Error:**

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.core.env.Environment]: Specified class is an interface.

Please help